# Input doesn't have value to store in a var

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, input

So the `input` in the `form` has the `id "fname"` and when i press submit, the function `values()` try to store the value in a `var` but it doesn't.

```js
var fname = "sss";

function values() {
  fname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:values()" method="GET">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Informations</legend>
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" class="formbtn">
</form>
<script src="javascript/cv_script.js"></script>
```

I have no idea why it's not working.
I have a proof that calling the function is working

and there is no errors like (can't store null value)

any solutions would be great

Thank you for your help!

here is the whole code↓

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Information Page</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/general.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            fieldset {
                border: 2px solid #007bff88;
                border-radius: 7px;
                width: 800px;
                margin-top: 10px;
                padding: 8px;
            }
            legend {
                width: auto;
                margin-left: 7px;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            select, textarea {
                background: none;
                border: 1px solid #007bff;
            }
            .formbtn {
                background: #007bff;
                color: #fff;
                border-radius: 5px;
                margin: 8px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                  Dropdown button
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
                </div>
              </div>
        </nav>

        <form action="javascript:values()" method="GET">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Personal Informations</legend>
                <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="fname">
                <br><br>
                <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="lname">
                <br><br>
                <label for="address">Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="address">
                <br><br>
                <label for="mobile">Mobile Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="mobile">
                <br><br>
                <label for="birth">Birthday:</label>
                <input type="date" id="birth">
                <br><br>
                <label for="gen">Gender:</label>
                <select name="gender" id="gen">
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <legend>Education & Hobbies</legend>
                <label for="level">Educational Level:</label>
                <input type="text" id="level">
                <br><br>
                <label for="place">University/School Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="place">
                <br><br>
                <label for="sec">Section:</label>
                <input type="text" id="sec">
                <br><br>
                <label>Hobbies & More:</label>
                <br>
                <textarea id="hobbies" cols="40" rows="4"></textarea>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" class="formbtn">
            <input type="reset" class="formbtn">
        </form>
        <script src="javascript/cv_script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"the function `values()` try to store the value in a var"_  that's not what it's doing though. What it's actually doing is setting the input's `value` property to the value of the `fname` variable which is "sss"

Comment: Using the `action` attribute like that is **not** how you trigger a JS function to run on form submit. Instead, use something like `document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", e => { e.preventDefault(); values() })`

Comment: the function worked with your code but still can't store the value in the var, and i was wrong doing it that way i should have switched between the value and the var, but i already know it doesn't store because i have a lot of values and vars doing the store thing.

Comment: I did it in another way and it worked Thanks for your help, much love ♥